# Abort trap: 6 error with arrays in c

Tags: c, string

The following code compiled fine yesterday for a while, started giving the `abort trap: 6` error at one point, then worked fine again for a while, and again started giving the same error. All the answers I've looked up deal with strings of some fixed specified length. I'm not very experienced in programming so any help as to why this is happening is appreciated. (The code is for computing the [Zeckendorf representation](https://oeis.org/wiki/Zeckendorf_representation).)

If I simply use `printf` to print the digits one by one instead of using strings the code works fine.

```
#include <string.h>

// helper function to compute the largest fibonacci number <= n
// this works fine
void maxfib(int n, int *index, int *fib) {
    int fib1 = 0;
    int fib2 = 1;
    int new = fib1 + fib2;
    *index = 2;
    while (new <= n) {
        fib1 = fib2;
        fib2 = new;
        new = fib1 + fib2;
        (*index)++;
        if (new == n) {
            *fib = new;
        }
    }
    *fib = fib2;
    (*index)--;
}

char *zeckendorf(int n) {
    int index;
    int newindex;
    int fib;
    char *ans = "";  // I'm guessing the error is coming from here
    while (n > 0) {
        maxfib(n, &index, &fib);
        n -= fib;
        maxfib(n, &newindex, &fib);
        strcat(ans, "1");
        for (int j = index - 1; j > newindex; j--) {
            strcat(ans, "0");
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Note that `if (new == n) { *fib = new; }` in the loop does nothing useful unless you add a `break;` after the assignment.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I was planning to delete that part after adding `*fib = fib2;
    (*index)--;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have two approaches when you want to receive a string from function in C

1. Caller allocates buffer (either statically or dynamically) and passes it to the callee as a pointer and size. Callee writes data to buffer. If it fits, it returns success as a status. If it does not fit, returns error. You may decide that in such case either buffer is untouched or it contains all data fitting in the size. You can choose whatever suits you better, just document it properly for future users (including you in future).
2. Callee allocates buffer dynamically, fills the buffer and returns pointer to the buffer. Caller must free the memory to avoid memory leak.

In your case the `zeckendorf()` function can determine how much memory is needed for the string. The index of first Fibonacci number less than parameter determines the length of result. Add 1 for terminating zero and you know how much memory you need to allocate.

So, if you choose first approach, you need to pass additional two parameters to `zeckendorf()` function: `char *buffer` and `int size` and write to the buffer `instead` of `ans`. And you need to have some marker to know if it's first iteration of the `while()` loop. If it is, after `maxfib(n, &index, &fib);` check the condition `index+1<=size`. If condition is true, you can proceed with your function. If not, you can return error immediately.

For second approach initialize the `ans` as:

```
char *ans = NULL;
```

after `maxfib(n, &index, &fib);` add:

```
if(ans==NULL) {
    ans=malloc(index+1);
}
```

and continue as you did. Return `ans` from function. Remember to call `free()` in caller, when result is no longer needed to avoid memory leak.

**In both cases** remember to write the terminating `\0` to buffer.

There is also a third approach. You can declare ans as:

```
static char ans[20];
```

inside `zeckendorf()`. Function shall behave as in first approach, but the buffer and its size is already hardcoded. I recommend to `#define BUFSIZE 20` and either declare variable as `static char ans[BUFSIZE];` and use `BUFSIZE` when checking available size. Please be aware that it works only in single threaded environment. And every call to `zeckendorf()` will overwrite the previous result. Consider following code.

```
char *a,*b;
a=zeckendorf(10);
b=zeckendorf(15);
printf("%s\n",a);
printf("%s\n",b);
```

The `zeckendorf()` function always return the same pointer. So `a` and `b` would pointer to the same buffer, where the string for `15` would be stored. So, you either need to store the result somewhere, or do processing in proper order:

```
a=zeckendorf(10);
printf("%s\n",a);
b=zeckendorf(15);
printf("%s\n",b);
```

As a rule of thumb majority (if not all) Linux standard C library function uses either first or third approach.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Your guess is quite correct:

```
char *ans = "";  // I'm guessing the error is coming from here
```

That makes `ans` point to a *read-only* array of *one character*, whose only element is the string terminator. Trying to append to this will write out of bounds and give you *undefined behavior*.

One solution is to [dynamically allocate memory](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) for the string, and if you don't know the size beforehand then you need to [reallocate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) to increase the size. If you do this, don't forget to add space for the string terminator, and to [free the memory](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) once you're done with it.

Comment: Not that it really matters which is the UB, but even without the attempted out-of-bounds access, it is UB to attempt to modify a string literal.

Comment: An alternative to dynamic allocation is `char ans[32] = "";` which gives you more than enough space for 64-bit integers (you could change 32 to 20 or thereabouts and still be OK).